# C# looping through HTML table rows added via javascript

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, html-table

I am trying to loop through an HTML table with runat="server" - but it's data is added dynamically via javascript.

```
<table runat="server" id="confirmCartTable" class="confirmCartTable cartGrid table">
   <tr>
       <th>ID</th>
       <th>Product</th>
       <th>Price</th>
       <th>Quantity</th>
       <th>Total</th>
   </tr>
</table>
```

It displays fine with 3 rows under it. But when I'm looping using C#:

```
    //get the datatable consisting of ProductID, Quantity, Price
    for(int i = 0;i < confirmCartTable.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
         **//confirmCartTable.Rows.Count is only 1, table headers only**
         HtmlTableRow row = confirmCartTable.Rows[i];
         dr = dt.NewRow();
         dr["ProductID"] = row.Cells[0].Controls[0];
         dr["Quantity"] = row.Cells[2].Controls[0];
         dr["Price"] = row.Cells[3].Controls[0];
         dt.Rows.Add(dr);
    }
```

Is it because the rows are added dynamically via JS? What can be the solution for this?

In the loop above, I need to add it to a DataTable. I got row.Cells[i].Controls[0] as System.Web.UI.LiteralControl.. I tried using

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
StringWriter tw = new StringWriter(sb);
HtmlTextWriter hw = new HtmlTextWriter(tw);

HtmlTable.RenderControl(hw);
dr[i] = sb.ToString();
```

It works, but this is too long (I have to do it for all 3 columns..)

Summing up the problem,

1. C# HtmlTable doesn't loop through the data added via JS
2. Get the inner html of each HtmlTableRow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with your logic is that you are adding rows dynamically via javascript will get lost on postback. dom manupulated via javascript are not sent back because it is not an input field.
You can circumvent this by having hiddenfield with run at server. on post back set the value of hiddenfield with innerhtml of table. on serverside query this hiddenfield to get the html. hope this is clear

Comment: Hi, sorry for the late reply. I changed the workaround of it.. Thanks a bunch!